# Git flow for multiple different variants of the same project

Tags: java, git, version-control

Say there's a legacy Java project A. That project for whatever reason has some things in it that are confidential (e.g. passwords, encryption keys, emails) and / or environment-specific (e.g. hard-coded paths, server names, emails). Due to the complexities involved, it doesn't seem possible to change the project to not contain the information in the source code.

At some point, a new outsourcing team joins the development. Given the above situation, the outsourcing team cannot get access to the project source verbatim. They have a separate development environment, so it's possible to make a separate copy of the project in their VCS that has the problems addressed (i.e. all the things needed are cleaned / updated as necessary to work in their environment). Let's call that version A2.

The workflow would generally include two things related to A and A2:

- The code can change at both sides (i.e. both A and A2 can change, A being changed by the original team and A2 by the outsourcing team), including having source code change conflicts
- There's a need to keep the two projects in sync. It's not required to have them in sync all the time, but it's important to have a relatively painless way to do that. It's assumed this must be a manual process when there are conflicts to be resolved

This workflow can be achieved by manually keeping two projects and merging between them.

Related questions:

- How would one go about managing the two versions with git, i.e. what are the options compared to manual merging?
- Is this the best setup or is there a better option?
- For new projects, what is the preferred way (in the sense - what do you do if you have similar situation?) to keep the confidential / environment-specific things out of source control? Is that a good thing anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is going to cause you pain. What you need to do is use `git filter-branch` to eliminate server names, passwords out and replace with a non-working general form - ie, it should not run - anywhere!

Next, set up smudge/clean scripts to alter the files that contain that information to populate the values to what they need to be for your solution to run on that local system only. There will be different parameters on your production environment compared to your development environment. The key is to have this information abstracted.

Now you should have no issue sharing the same repository with the outsourced team. Managing branches in one repo versus scrubbing commits between to repos is way easier.

Answer (score 0):

@icyrock.com: That seems the recipe for a disaster.

My suggestion is to separate source code from sensible data.
Note that this is a more general suggestion, you probably want to keep that sensible data safely stored and with limited access.

Steps:
1. remove every sensible data from the source code,
2. create a new git repository that contains that sensible data
3. reference sensible data from the original source code (this depends on the programming language, Java is not my field of expertise)

At this point the "cleaned" source code can be safely shared with the outsourcing team, thay will not have access to the "sensible data" repo, but they probably have a similar repo with their own version of that sensible data (i.e. "demo" or "trial" or "non-production" paths, server names, emails).
Of course the above is needed if the outsourcing team should be put in a position to test their changes in a test environment, which I strongly assume as a MUST have. They ARE doing tests, aren't they?

This will drastically reduce if not eliminate as a whole any problem related to big messy merge between 2 copy of the same stuff being actively developed in parallel.